# Align to the left google wallet logo

Tags: javascript, html, android-pay

In my website http://www.theprinterdepo.com, left bottom, I have the google wallet logo.

I rendered this logo with the code they provided, however I cant align it to the left.  I tried style align left in the div they provided but it looks like the code is rewritten by them with the Javascript code.

```
<div id="googleCheckoutLogo"></div><script src='https://checkout.google.com/buttons/logos?merchant_id=909856425434813&loc=en&f=png' ></script>
```

Comment: There's no such css property called "align".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add these lines to your CSS

```
#badge_container {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

The element (assumably placed by google) has a `padding-left` set. You don't want that. By using the `!important` keyword, this property will stick.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to target the CSS? if so you can remove the left padding from `#badge_container {}`